# Custom Validation in SugarCRM old (v6)

Tags: javascript, sugarcrm

I'm a bit stuck, since I need to know a bit better the syntax of this type of custom validation in sugarCRM.

I have this kind of validation:

```
SUGAR.util.doWhen("typeof(check_form) != 'undefined' && typeof check_form == 'function'", function() {
```

Could someone explain to me how the syntax or parameters of that function work?
I need to do two validations to two new fields that I have added but i dont know how to declare it in the file for this.

I checked replicating the function with my two validations but when wanting to save in the users module, nothing happens since I guess when replicating the function, sugarCRM does not know what to do.

I have seen that this type of validation applied for version 6 of sugarcrm but I have not been able to find documentation about it.

Answer (score 1):

Kindly add create custom js file and call below function.

```
function override_check_form() {
window.old_check_form = window.check_form;
var formname = 'EditView';
window.check_form = function(formname) {
    clear_all_errors();
    window.formToCheck = formname;
    // condition start
    var field_name =  $('#field_name').find("option:selected").text();
    var flag = true;
    if(!field_name){
        add_error_style('EditView','field_name','Missing required field: Field Name');
        var flag = false;
    }
    // condition end
    if (flag) {
        return window.old_check_form(formname);
    }
    return false;
}
```

}